# Angular 6 y bootstrap 4 sidebar y navbar que no recargue en cada enlace

Tags: angular, rutas

Cual es la forma correcta de crear navbar y sidebar en angular,
cuando ingreso en un enlace de mi proyecto, recarga el sidebar y el navbar y eso no parece que fuera correcto.
También hay paginas en las que no deseo mostrar el sidebar.

Mis rutas están declaradas de la sgte manera.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path:'',
    component:HomeComponent,
    canActivate:[AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '',
        component: SidebarComponent
      },
      { path: '',
        outlet: 'navbar',
        component: NavbarComponent
      }

    ]
  },
  {
    path:'consulta',
    component:ConsultaComponent,
    canActivate:[AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '',
        component: SidebarComponent
      },
      { path: '',
        outlet: 'navbar',
        component: NavbarComponent
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    path: "login",
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: "repdepto/:idDepto",
    component: RepdeptoComponent,
    canActivate:[AuthGuard],
  }
])
```

Comment: Por favor, muestra el código de tu navbar, es decir el html

Comment: Mira no se cual es la manera correcta pero yo he visto ejemplos en github donde ya esta el proyecto mas o menos estructurado y acomodado de una manera que funciona todo muy bien y te podrías basar en uno de estos ejemplos, te anexo una liga: https://github.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tenés que hacer es crear una ruta sin componente. Lo que [en la documentación](https://angular.io/guide/router#component-less-route-grouping-routes-without-a-component) se conoce como `Component-less route`. Esa ruta sin componente debe contener al `sidebar` y al `navbar` como hijos, pero en los `router-outlet`s correspondientes.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  // Primero las rutas en donde no se requieren SidebarComponent
  {
    path: "login",
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: "repdepto/:idDepto",
    component: RepdeptoComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  // Ahora la ruta vacía que contiene los componentes de navegación
  {
    path: '',   // Ruta sin componente
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        outlet: 'navbar',
        component: NavbarComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        outlet: 'sidebar',
        component: SidebarComponent
      },
      // Los componentes principales también son hijos de
      // la ruta sin componente
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'consulta',
        component: ConsultaComponent,
      }
    ]
  },
])
```

---

Los componentes que no van a tener `sidebar` ni `navbar` deben ir primero en el `Router` para que no caigan dentro de la ruta sin componente.